# Factoring polynomials of degree 6 over extension fields.

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, factoring

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients that is irreducible over the integers and has degree 6.

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $F$. Then we can ask, whether there exist intermediate fields $K$, $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq K\subseteq L$, such that A) $f(x)$ factors in a non-trivial way  in $K[X]$, B) $K$ does not contain any of the zeros of $f(x)$, and C) the degree condition $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=6$ is satisfied.

I wonder if there are $f(x)$ and distinct intermediate fields $K_1$ and $K_2$ such that $f(x) = g_1(x)h_1(x) = g_2(x)h_2(x)$ where $g_1$ and $h_1$ have coefficients in $K_1$ and are of degree 3 and where $g_2$ and $h_2$ have coefficients in $K_2$ and are of degree 3.

That is the main question. However I have some more.

I also wonder if it is possible that $f(x)=q(x^2)$ where $q$ is also an irreducible polynomial.

A more general question is made if we replace $6$ with $2p$ where $p$ is an odd prime and the degrees of the factors are replaced by $p$ ( instead of $3$).

Clearly I considered 2 factorisations , we could also ask how many factorizations and $K_n$ can occur at most for degree $2p$.

A conjecture could be $n = p/3 + O(1)$.
Let $t(p)=n$. Then for instance $t(2) = 2$ , $t(3)=2$,$t(5)=2$,$t(7)=3$ which seems imho to weakly suggest $t(p) =$ primecountingfunction$(t)/3 + O(1).$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Factoring polynomials of degree 6 in 2 ways.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245972/factoring-polynomials-of-degree-6-in-2-ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the Galois group of $f$ be the dihedral group of order 12. This has a subgroup of order 2 corresponding to rotating a hexagon through $\pi$. The fixed field of this subgroup should be an extension of degree 6 in which $f$ is reducible but has no root.

EDIT: A simple example. $f(x)=x^6-2$ is irreducible over the rationals and has degree 6. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^3-2$. Then $$f(x)=(x^2-\root3\of2)(x^2-\omega\root3\of2)(x^2-\omega^2\root3\of2)$$ over $K$, where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$, $K$ contains no zeros of $f$, and $K$ is of degree $6$ over the rationals.

MORE EDIT: Just to clarify, the above is meant as an answer to the question in the second paragraph that goes from "Then we can ask," to conditions A). B). and C).

Comment: Im not so good with Galois theory. So how is this an answer ?

Comment: I have added an illustrative example.

Comment: Well thanks for the example. But I still do not understand. Is this a yes or a no ? you have 3 factors of degree 2 rather than 2 factors of degree 3.

Comment: Mick, you have about 5 questions in the body of your question. I have answered the first one, the one that starts "Then we can ask," and ends with condition C). I don't think it's a good idea to ask half-a-dozen questions in one. If you can work out how to answer your other questions from what I've done for your first question, good --- then you can post the answers. If you can't answer your other questions, then my advice is to post them as new questions, one at a time, with time out to ponder the answers to each before posting the next, and with links back to this question.

Comment: I voted for close because I asked a new question basicly the same ...